# MySQL delete row foreign key on multitable?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a big problem.
I need delete all row on multitable...on this model DB

http://i62.tinypic.com/m7fhap.png

Because when I try (`DELETE FROM alergia WHERE Grupo = 'Alergia1'`) return this error

```
 ERROR 1451: 1451: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`odontologia`.`alergico`, CONSTRAINT `fk_Personas_has_Alergia_Alergia1` FOREIGN KEY (`Alergia_ID`) REFERENCES `alergia` (`ID`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
```

SQL Statement:

```
DELETE FROM `odontologia`.`alergia` WHERE `ID`='2'"
```

I can do the deletion, but using some variables and sql statements. 
I was reading and talking about DELETE CASCADE but I can not. 
I need to delete any records in tables that have a direct or indirect relationship with the ID ALERGIAGRUPO ... thank you very much for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do a join with Alergico and delete corresponding foreign key rows first

In case you have multiple such foreign key relations ships, you have to delete it from all such tables.

```
DELETE FROM Alergico
WHERE Alergia_ID in ( SELECT ID FROM Alergia where ID= 2)
```

Then you can do the deletion from Alergia

```
DELETE FROM Alergia where ID =2
```

Comment: Since I was about this idea. there is only a single solution ?. use some sentences to go deleting each relationship in each table. 
There is not a single statement that will automatically do that?

Comment: Yes there is no other solution or modify it to have on delete cascade option

Comment: Hey man... THANK.. I can config the DELETE CASCADE thank for u help! Greetings from Ecuador !

Comment: @StalinJavierPalaciosFlores, you can accept the answer, if it is useful to you

Comment: is ok!. You can helpme again? .. I have this statement.
 delete from alergiatipo where ID in (select alergiatipo.ID from alergia,alergiatipo where alergia.AlergiaTipo_ID = alergiatipo.iD and alergia.ID in (select alergia.ID from alergia,alergiagrupo where alergia.AlergiaGrupo_ID = alergiagrupo.ID AND alergiagrupo.ID = '2')); but return this error. Error Code: 1093. You can't specify target table 'alergiatipo' for update in FROM clause
You know how You know how to fix it

Comment: @StalinJavierPalaciosFlores,  delete from alergiatipo where ID in (select ID from (select alergiatipo.ID from alergia,alergiatipo where alergia.AlergiaTipo_ID = alergiatipo.iD and alergia.ID in (select alergia.ID from alergia,alergiagrupo where alergia.AlergiaGrupo_ID = alergiagrupo.ID AND alergiagrupo.ID = '2')));

Comment: another error with your statement. 
Error Code: 1248. Every derived table must have its own alias

Comment: delete from alergiatipo where ID in (select ID from (select alergiatipo.ID from alergia,alergiatipo where alergia.AlergiaTipo_ID = alergiatipo.iD and alergia.ID in (select alergia.ID from alergia,alergiagrupo where alergia.AlergiaGrupo_ID = alergiagrupo.ID AND alergiagrupo.ID = '2')) as TableA);

Comment: Another error. Best That I do in part 2 using the program . ALSO thanks u su much! (y)